# Rails 3: odd Actionview template error when using if elsif statement

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using an if elsif elsif elsif end statement and I"m getting the following error as ActionView is looking for a create.js.erb file because its the name of the method. I tried to specify the :action specifically but it isn't working. If I remove the `elsifs` and use just a single `if end` statement it renders the `:action 'create_like`'.. shown below:

```
def create
      if params[:liked_id]
        @post = Post.find(params[:appreciation][:liked_id])
        current_user.like!(@post)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to @post }
          format.js  { render :action => "create_like" }
        end
      end
    end
```

## ERROR

```
 ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template appreciations/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :haml], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", "*/*"], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Users/iHal/Desktop/WORK/GP/app/views", "/Users/iHal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/bundler/gems/rails_admin-0060ad2d78ed/app/views", "/Users/iHal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.0/app/views", "/Users/iHal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3/gems/devise-1.3.4/app/views"):
```

### UsersController

```
class AppreciationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

def create
  if params[:liked_id]
    @post = Post.find(params[:appreciation][:liked_id])
    current_user.like!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js  { render :action => "create_like" }
    end
  elsif params[:voted_id]
    @post = Post.find(params[:appreciation][:voted_id])
    current_user.vote!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js  { render :action => "create_vote" }
    end
  elsif params[:thanked_id]
    @post = Post.find(params[:appreciation][:thanked_id])
    current_user.thank!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js  {render :action => 'create_thank'} 
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  if params[:liked_id]
    @post = Appreciation.find(params[:id]).liked
    current_user.unlike!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js { render :action => "destroy_like" }
    end
  elsif params[:vote_id]
    @post = Appreciation.find(params[:id]).voted
    current_user.unvote!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js { render :action => "destroy_vote" }
    end
  elsif params[:thanked_id]
    @post = Appreciation.find(params[:id]).thanked
    current_user.unthank!(@post)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post }
      format.js { render :action => "destroy_thank" }
    end
  end
end
  end
```

## edit

```
Started POST "/appreciations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-24 23:57:18 -0700
  Processing by AppreciationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T3PeKRaSJSrESFTOCQ7+4LiM4BKaWkcaQ6cXpSqK38k=", "appreciation"=>{"liked_id"=>"75"}, "commit"=>"Like"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
Completed   in 309ms
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template appreciations/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :haml], :formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript",...
```

Comment: Check the params provided to create, as from your code, if none of `linked_id`, `voted_id` or `thanked_id` is provided, default template will be used. Or better add `render :status => 400` before final end of `def create`.

Comment: I edited above to show the request and that its completed, that's what you were thinking right? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, so now the answer is simple, use short version of `render`, like: `render 'create_like'`

Comment: I wish that was it but its doesnt change anything for me :(  I'm very confused why it would work properly without the elsif statments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you should call `return` after each `respond_to`. Because after called if, the method process continued to the end and trying to call render default. For example:

```
render 'your_template' and return
```

Or in your case

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @post }
  format.js  { render :action => "create_like" }
end and return
```

Comment: Dang, I really wished this worked, was thinking it makes perfect sense but unfortunately nothing changes :(((

Comment: thanks for the help it was actually because I didnt have params[:appreciation][:thanked_id] and so on...

Comment: Wait, but in your question you provided request log, and there was `"appreciation"=>{"liked_id"=>"75"},` so needed param was there? Ahh, but before that you checked `params[:liked_id]` that was missing. Thanks for update.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the parameters from your request carefully, notice that you're not passing any of `params[:liked_id]`, `params[:voted_id]` or `params[:thanked_id]`:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T3PeKRaSJSrESFTOCQ7+4LiM4BKaWkcaQ6cXpSqK38k=", "appreciation"=>{"liked_id"=>"75"}, "commit"=>"Like"}
```

You are rather passing `params[:appreciation][:liked_id]`. It seems you should change your conditions to:

```
def create
  if params[:appreciation][:liked_id]
    # ...
  elsif params[:appreciation][:voted_id]
    # ...
  elsif params[:appreciation][:thanked_id]
    # ...
  end
end
```